# Разница между двумя версиями одного кода

Tags: python, парсер

первый вариант:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


def get_html(_):
    r = requests.get(_)
    return r.text


def get_data(html_code):
    soup = BS(html_code, 'lxml')
    spans = soup.find('span').text
    return spans


def main():
    url = 'https://yandex.ru/pogoda/213'
    print(get_data(get_html(url)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

второй вариант:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


def get_data(html_code):
    soup = BS(html_code, 'lxml')
    spans = soup.find('span').text
    return spans


def main():
    url = 'https://yandex.ru/pogoda/213'
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text # вернули html-код сайта
    print(get_data(r.text))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

не могу понять почему не работает второй вариант, ведь аргумент для функции get_data аналогичный получается.

Comment: Может из-за того, что используете return для выхода из метода

Comment: а как по другому присвоить переменной значение на выходе из функции?

Comment: для запросов вообще должен быть отдельный метод, а вы все в кучу смешали

Comment: `return r.text # вернули html-код сайта` - куда вернули? У вас код вызывающий функцию main возвращенное значение никак не обрабатывает. В данном случае return просто прерывает функцию main и возвращает r.text в никуда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы хотите, чтобы print что-то напечатал уже после того, как вы вернули управление из функции? Так не получится. Надо сначала напечатать, а потом выходить:

```
print(get_data(r.text)) # сначала напечатали
return r.text # потом вернули html-код сайта
```

И если вы хотите как-то использовать то, что вернула функция, надо что-то с результатом сделать - присвоить куда-то или напечатать:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main()) # печатаем то, что вернула функция
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас все в куче, разделите эту кучу на составные части:

```
def get_html(r):
    return BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")

def request(url, params):
    while True:
        try:
            r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=header)
            if(r.status_code == 200):
                return r.text
            else:
                print("Ожидание 1 секунда")
                time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Ожидание 1 секунда", e)
            time.sleep(1)

def get_data(html):
    spans = html.find('span').text
    return spans

def parse():
    url = ""
    r = request(url, None)
    html = get_html(r)
    spans = get_data(html)
```

Примерно так, метод request можно менять в зависимости от функционала и требуемой обработки ошибки